# newbie asking about reading NSMutableArray from and saving NSMutableArray to documents file

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

On `viewDidLoad`, my application populates the NSMutableArray `arrayOfHaiku`, which is an array of `NSDictionary` items, as follows:

```
 NSError *error;
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //1
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"haiku.plist"];
 NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
 if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
 {
 NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"haiku" ofType:@"plist"];
 [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error];
 }
 self.arrayOfHaiku = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
```

While using the application, the user adds items to `self.arrayOfHaiku`.  As of now I include the following code in `viewDidUnload`:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //1
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"haiku.plist"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
{
    [self.arrayOfHaiku writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}
```

Here are my questions:

1. Does my code for `viewDidUnload` a) simply write over the document storing the array in the Documents folder (that is, the array accessed in `viewDidLoad`) with the new, expanded array (which is what I want to do), or does it b) append the new, expanded array to the array already stored in the Documents folder so that I end up with an array that's more than twice as long with a bunch of repeats?
2. If the answer is "b)", what do I need to change to do "a)"?
3. Is it better a) to do it the way I'm doing it, at `viewDidUnload`, or b) to expand the array in the documents folder each time the user adds an item to self.arrayOfHaiku?
4. If the answer is "b)", what do I need to change to do "b)"?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If the file exists, it will be overwritten, else it will be created (option a).
2. It all depends on the number of records. If you have a huge number then rewriting them everytime could be expensive. Otherwise you have to look to another solution. I honestly would not suggest using `viewDidUnload` because it might not fire in certain circumstances for example, if the app is backgrounded.
3. Unfortunately, there is no ready function for 'updating' a plist with dictionary objects like `writeToFile:` . You can use NSFileHandler's `fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:` function but then you would have to change the plist file manually (Which i dont think is a simple process).

I personally would suggest using [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) unless your data structure is very simple and 'option a' would not be an expensive process.

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so very, very much!  The data structure is very simple (`self.arrayOfHaiku` is an array of `NSDictionary` items each one of which contains exactly two objects and two keys) and self.arrayOfHaiku is unlikely ever to be contain than 200 or 300 items, so I'll try it in a few places--see how much it costs to do it every time, or whether it makes a difference putting it elsewhere--but I hadn't thought about that issue with `viewDidUnload` so in any case I'll find a new home for it.  Thank you so very, very much!